# How to change influxdb storage location

Tags: docker, kubernetes, influxdb

I have installed influxdb in docker container (Kubernetes) and I have mounted a persistent volume to that container. But influxdb is not writing data to that volume. 
Can anyone please tell me steps, so that influxdb will write data in particular volume. 
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

```
   $ docker run -p 8083:8083 -p 8086:8086 \
          -v $PWD:/var/lib/influxdb \
          influxdb
```

Modify $PWD with the path to external volume.

**Long answer:**

```
docker run -p 8083:8083 -p 8086:8086 influxdb
```

By default this will store the data in /var/lib/influxdb. All InfluxDB data lives in there. To make that a persistent volume (recommended):

```
$ docker run -p 8083:8083 -p 8086:8086 \
      -v $PWD:/var/lib/influxdb \
      influxdb
```

Modify $PWD to the directory where you want to store data associated with the InfluxDB container.

For example,

```
 $ docker run -p 8083:8083 -p 8086:8086 \
              -v /your/home:/var/lib/influxdb \
              influxdb
```

This will store the influx data in /your/home on the host.

Comment: Thank you for reply. What if I want to store into /your/home and also I want to use my own config file. what should be the command?

Comment: I have on more question. I started the Linux Docker Container with the volume mount. When i'am accessing the container and browse to the folder there is only one database under /var/lib/influxdb which is called _internal. My python script shows me instead another database which ist called test_database. Where is this database located?

Answer (score 9):

**For InfluxDB 2.0**:

In InfluxDB 2.0 (or 2.0.3 at least) the data directory has changed. Things are now stored under `~/.influxdbv2` by default (where `~` is `/root/` in the `quay.io/influxdb/influxdb:v2.0.3` image), which does not seem very docker-ish to me.

Actually, there are 2 data storages for [bolt](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/config-options/#bolt-path) (various key-value configurations) and [engine](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/config-options/#engine-path) (the TSM database). If you like, you could change them via the `--engine-path=/data/engine` --bolt-path=`/data/bolt` paramaters to `influxd`.

The following `docker-compose.yml` should therefore store the InfluxDB2 data into a volume.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  influxdb:
    image: 'quay.io/influxdb/influxdb:v2.0.3'
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '8086:8086'
    volumes:
      - data:/root/.influxdbv2
volumes:
  data:
```

Right now, there is *no* official `_/influxdb:2.0` on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/influxdb) (see also [influxdb#16649](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/16649)). I hope that this image (once released) has some better defaults (`quay.io/influxdb/influxdb:v2.0.3` does not even create an anonymous volume; any data is lost therefore once the container is removed). So please check Docker Hub if there is an image InfluxDB 2.0 before trying these things here.

Answer (score 6):

**For InfluxDB 2.0.4:**

There is now a official image on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/influxdb). But unlike the `quay.io/influxdb/influxdb:v2.0.4` image, where data is stored in `/root/.influxdbv2`, you have to mount `/var/lib/influxdb2` as a volume.

Answer (score 3):

If you pulled official influxdb image from docker library, the default path for data files is:

```
/var/lib/influxdb
```

To verify, Run an standalone instance:

```
docker run -p 8083:8083 -p 8086:8086 \
      -v $PWD:/var/lib/influxdb \
      influxdb
```

To check out the default config:

```
docker run --rm influxdb influxd config > influxdb.conf
```

Then use `vim influxdb.conf`

To run influxdb with custom config:

```
docker run -p 8086:8086 \
      -v $PWD/influxdb.conf:/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf:ro \
      influxdb -config /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
```